# How to add a response header before forwarding to another resource

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, httpresponse

I hava a servlet which handles some resources files, and I need to add a response header before I forward the request to the real jsp file.

```
response.setHeader("a", "b");
request.getRequestDispatcher("1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I need to send that header directly to the browser, But it did not work, I tried to use firebug to watch the http request and its response, how can I do that?

Comment: How do you know that it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.include(request, response)` instead. Probably it's a `.forward()` feature to fully clean response object before forwarding.

See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it is not working? Please read this [JR thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/362039/Servlets/java/response-setHeader-not-working), I believe you are expecting similar thing.

Comment: No, I did try to get the header in 1.jsp through request object, I just use "Firebug" to watch the http headers, my custom header does not show in "1.jsp"

Comment: @virsir: Would you mind posting the relevant snippet of what you get in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some data added by the servlet in the 1.jsp code, I suggest you use request.setAttribute method. response.addHeader/setHeader put some data into the response'header. Generally the data in the response header is used by the browser.

Comment: Yes, I just need to send a header to browser directly

Comment: response.addHeader will add a response header and the browser will receive it. I have tested the code. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

The headers are being cleaned up. Just curious, what stops you from using `request.setAttribute()`?